# Can't get onclick to show more text

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm pretty new in programming and wanted to make a button to show more. but yeah, the button doesn't work whatever i do. I have made a block which should drop down to reveal more text if it wasn't clear here under. Thank you hundred times over if you could help a newbie.

**Here is the Javascript**

```
function hejhej()
    var x = document.getElementById("button-area").href;
    document.getElementById("show-more").InnerHTML = x;

    button.onclick = function() {
        if(content.className =="open")
        //shrink the box
        content.ClassName = "";
        button.innerHTML = "Show More"

    } else{
        //Expand the box
        content.ClassName = "open";
        button.innerHTML = "Show Less"
     
    }
```

And the CSS to drop down the text

```
  .show-more {
      font-family: calibri;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #1594e5;
      color: #fff;
      width: 100px;
      height: 50px;
      font-size: 24px;
      border-color: #1594e5;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
  }
  .button-area {
      width: 527px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: #1e1e1e;
      color: #E7E1D1;
      margin: 0px;
      margin-top: -4px;
      position: relative;

      max-height: 100px;
      overflow: hidden;

      /* Till övergångar. */
      -webkit-transition: max-height 0.7s;
      -moz-transition: max-height 0.7s;
      transition: max-height 0.7s;

  }
  #button-area.open {
      max-height: 400px;

      /* Till övgergångar neråt */
      -webkit-transition: max-height 0.7s;
      -moz-transition: max-height 0.7s;
      transition: max-height 0.7s;
  }
```

**And if it is for any use, the normal HTML code**

```
<div class="button-area">    
    Test test very much test as i said i tested the test
</div>

<button onclick="hejhej()" class="show-more">Tryck</button>
<script src="src/js/ExtremtJava.js"></script>
```

Comment: That function doesn't look like it has opening and closing brackets `{ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this gets you started. I'm commenting mostly of what I've changed to your code but you primarily have a ton of syntax errors.

```js
// Fixed a ton of syntax errors. Closed functions properly and removed excess 
//brackets/code

function hejhej() {
   var buttonArea = document.getElementById( 'button-area' );
   if (
      buttonArea.classList.contains( 'open' ) 
    ) {
      //shrink the box
      buttonArea.innerHTML = "Show More";
      buttonArea.classList.remove( "open" );      
    }
   else {
      //Expand the box
      buttonArea.innerHTML = "Show Less";
      buttonArea.classList.add( "open" );      
  }
 }
```

```css
.show-more {
  font-family: calibri;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #1594e5;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-color: #1594e5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.button-area {
  width: 527px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  color: #E7E1D1;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;

  /* Till övergångar. */
  -webkit-transition: max-height, height: 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: max-height, height: 0.7s;
  transition: max-height, height 0.7s;  
}
.open {
  height: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-area" id="button-area">    <!-- added missing id -->
    Test test very much test as i said i tested the test
</div>

<button onclick="hejhej()" class="show-more">Tryck</button>
```

To answer your question in the comments: The reason why "show more" and "show less" are replacing your original text is because you're changing the `innerHTML` of that element. Remove those lines of code and your original text will stay. See below:

```js
// Fixed a ton of syntax errors. Closed functions properly and removed excess 
//brackets/code

function hejhej() {
   var buttonArea = document.getElementById( 'button-area' );
   if (
      buttonArea.classList.contains( 'open' ) 
    ) {
      //shrink the box
      buttonArea.classList.remove( "open" );      
    }
   else {
      //Expand the box
      buttonArea.classList.add( "open" );      
  }
 }
```

```css
.show-more {
  font-family: calibri;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #1594e5;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-color: #1594e5;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.button-area {
  width: 527px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  color: #E7E1D1;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;

  /* Till övergångar. */
  -webkit-transition: max-height, height: 0.7s;
  -moz-transition: max-height, height: 0.7s;
  transition: max-height, height 0.7s;  
}
.open {
  height: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-area" id="button-area">    <!-- added missing id -->
    Test test very much test as i said i tested the test
</div>

<button onclick="hejhej()" class="show-more">Tryck</button>
```

Comment: Hey! first of all, thanks for the help, the code works now. But.. now instead of the text in the div
 `<div class="button-area" id="button-area">

    Test test very much test as i said i tested the test
</div>`
the show more or less is shown which after looking at the code is understandable because that's how i wrote it originally. I may be dumb but i'm also new in Javascript. How do i make the div text be inside instead?

Comment: Thank you so much, struggled alot with this!